# hexlify and unhexlify functions in C

Tags: c, string, char

Please help... I'm trying to learn C types conversion.

This code works well only converting some hex chars as 1, 2, 3. For others, also changing string or reduce string length, the conversion fails...

I'll put the code below... Anyone can explain me where the code is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a2v(char c)
{
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
    {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f'))
    {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    else return 0;
}

char v2a(int c)
{
    const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    return hex[c];
}

char *unhexlify(char *hstr)
{
    char *bstr = malloc((strlen(hstr) / 2) + 1);
    char *pbstr = bstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(hstr); i += 2)
    {
        *pbstr++ = (a2v(hstr[i]) << 4) + a2v(hstr[i + 1]);
    }
    *pbstr++ = '\0';
    return bstr;
}

char *hexlify(char *bstr)
{
    char *hstr = malloc((strlen(bstr) * 2) + 1);
    char *phstr = hstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(bstr); i++)
    {
        *phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i] >> 4) & 0xFF);
        *phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i]) & 0xFF);
    }
    *phstr++ = '\0';
    return hstr;
}

int main()
{
    char *title = "... Trying to convert hex into binary string and back again ?! ...";
    printf("%s\n\n", title);

    char *input = "0123456789abcdef\0";
    printf("Original: %s (%d)\n\n", input, (int)strlen(input));

    char *input_bin = unhexlify(input);
    printf("Bin: %s (%d)\n\n", input_bin, (int)strlen(input_bin));

    char *input_hex = hexlify(input_bin);
    printf("Hex: %s (%d)\n\n", input_hex, (int)strlen(input_hex));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the data created by `unhexlify` would be a printable string? It basically creates an array of arbitrary integer values, which might or might not be printable.

Comment: This sounds like the pefect opportunity to learn how to use your debugger: some non-trivial piece of code with a problem.

Comment: I know binary string cannot be printable. It s the return hex string the problem. I know I m wrong somewhere...

Comment: `v2a((bstr[i]) & 0xFF)` passes into `v2a()` a value in the 0 - 255 range.  Looks like that function only  handles 0 to 15.  Did you want `v2a((bstr[i]) & 0x0F)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!

Based on [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)'s answer, the mistake was into hexlify function:

```
*phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i] >> 4) & 0x0F);
*phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i]) & 0x0F);
```

Masks was wrong! I will study much more!

PS = I added some code in order to handle NULL binary character (0), that truncates string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a2v(char c)
{
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
    {
        return c - '0';
    }
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f'))
    {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
    else return 0;
}

char v2a(int c)
{
    const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    return hex[c];
}

char *unhexlify(char *hstr)
{
    char *bstr = malloc((strlen(hstr) / 2) + 1);
    char *pbstr = bstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(hstr); i += 2)
    {
        char c = (a2v(hstr[i]) << 4) + a2v(hstr[i + 1]);
        if (c == 0) {
            *pbstr++ = -128;
        } else {
            *pbstr++ = c;
        }
    }
    *pbstr++ = '\0';
    return bstr;
}

char *hexlify(char *bstr)
{
    char *hstr = malloc((strlen(bstr) * 2) + 1);
    char *phstr = hstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(bstr); i++)
    {
        if (bstr[i] == -128)
        {
            *phstr++ = '0';
            *phstr++ = '0';
        } else {
            *phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i] >> 4) & 0x0F);
            *phstr++ = v2a((bstr[i]) & 0x0F);
        }   
    }
    *phstr++ = '\0';
    return hstr;
}

int main()
{
    printf("... Trying to convert hex into binary string and back again ?! ...\n\n");

    char *input = "070790ca8fd8058b455f13dd698a4eed028cb0efc13907f681604676d69e57affe299aae7c91fd000000005271266004e4cd7f52548153f8f78b76840aeca16e91bac0ebeb4d74ff3ce3c901\0";

    char *input_bin = unhexlify(input);
    char *input_hex = hexlify(input_bin);

    printf("Input: %s (%d)\n\n", input, strlen(input));
    printf("Output: %s (%d)\n\n", input_hex, strlen(input_hex));

    if (strcmp(input, input_hex) == 0)
    {
        printf("Input and output are EQUALS !\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Input and output are NOT EQUALS !\n\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Regards, Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Updated Version of @Kevin's answer:

```
int a2v(char c) {
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) return c - '0';
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f')) return c - 'a' + 10;
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F')) return c - 'A' + 10;
    else return 0;
}

char v2a(int c) {
    const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    return hex[c];
}


char *hexlify(char *bstr) {
    char *hstr=malloc((strlen(bstr)*2)+1);
    bzero(hstr,(strlen(bstr)*2)+1);
    char *phstr=hstr;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(bstr);i++) {
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i]>>4)&0x0F);
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i])&0x0F);
    }
    *phstr++ ='\0';
    return hstr;
}
char *hexlifyn(char *bstr, uint str_len) {
    char *hstr=malloc((str_len*2)+1);
    bzero(hstr,(str_len*2)+1);
    char *phstr=hstr;
    for(int i=0; i<str_len;i++) {
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i]>>4)&0x0F);
        *phstr++ =v2a((bstr[i])&0x0F);
    }
    *phstr++ ='\0';
    return hstr;
}

char *unhexlify(char *hstr) {
    char *bstr=malloc((strlen(hstr)/2)+1);
    bzero(bstr,(strlen(hstr)/2)+1);
    char *pbstr=bstr;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(hstr); i += 2)
        *pbstr++ =(a2v(hstr[i])<<4)+a2v(hstr[i+1]);
    *pbstr++ ='\0';
    return bstr;
}
char *unhexlifyn(char *hstr, uint str_len) {
    char *bstr=malloc((str_len/2)+1);
    bzero(bstr,(str_len/2)+1);
    char *pbstr=bstr;
    for(int i=0;i<str_len; i += 2)
        *pbstr++ =(a2v(hstr[i])<<4)+a2v(hstr[i+1]);
    *pbstr++ ='\0';
    return bstr;
}
```